# `configure` requires python-devel header files

Tags: python, bash, gnu-make, configure, python-development-mode

So i am trying to build gnu-solfege for my musical needs but i when i `./configure` it show this error

[image]

i have installed python-package on my fedora machine.

i think i need to run it thru `configure` because i believe its still trying to add headers from python that is running/configured instead of the python-devel package

Comment: what's the problem to install `python-dev` as is written in the message?

Comment: I am not using debian or its derivatives so i can't install "python-dev" but i can install "python-devel" which i have:)

Comment: it makes sense :) maybe you need to install python3-devel, but I'm not sure regarding this

Comment: Exactly. i have that installed already. i have the required python packages installed but i am having trouble configuring linux to use python-devel instead of default one. thanks for contributing tho :)